# Loading data into collection with nested document using pyspark

Tags: mongodb, pyspark

I have a csv file as bellow :

```
 FirstName,lastName,age,personId,emailAddress
 John, Doe,22,128876,jdoe@mymail.com 
 Sue, Sunny, 44, 345346, ssunny@mymail.com 
 Mick, Brown, 34, 567876, mbrown@mymail.com
```

I am trying to load the file via pyspark and load it in my mongodb collection. However the schema and my collection is not flat and is as below:

```
personId: {type: number}, 
personInfo:{ 
   firstName:String, 
   lastName: String,
   age:number, 
   email: String
}
```

How can I convert a flat input file to a dataframe with subdocument?

This is the code for loading flat file into flat structure but I would like to know how can I modify it to work with my collection that have subdocument

```
    spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Bulk Load") \
    .master("local[*]") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/Test.person") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/Test.person") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1") \
    .getOrCreate()


    spark.conf.set("spark.sql.repl.eagerEval.enabled", True)

    df = spark.read.csv("sampledata.csv",header=True,inferSchema=True) 

   
    df.write.format("mongo").mode("append").option("database","Test").option("collection", "person").save()
```

Please note that above example is just to simply illustrate the issue that I am having.